# Data Type of Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, types

Iam using a service called AdminService to update the user role in the app

but when i call the service to pass it a parameter it show an error about the datatype like ."Argument of type 'any[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'"

AdminService:

```
updateUserRoles(username: string, roles: string) {
return this.http.post<string[]>(this.baseUrl + 'admin/edit-roles/' + username + '?roles=' + roles, {})
```

}

user-Management Component:

```
 openRolesModal(user: User) {
const config = {
  class: 'modal-dialog-centered',
  initialState: {
    username: user.username,
    availableRoles: this.availableRoles,
    selectedRoles: [...user.roles]
  }
}
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(RolesModalComponent, config);
this.bsModalRef.onHide?.subscribe({
  next: () => {
    const selectedRoles = this.bsModalRef.content?.selectedRoles;
    if (!this.arrayEqual(selectedRoles, user.roles)) {
      this.adminService.updateUserRoles(user.username, selectedRoles).subscribe({
        next: roles => user.roles = roles
      })
    }
  }
})
```

}

the error occurs of using `string[]` as return type of the service function but the `selectedRoles` property can not return as string[],

how can i correct it or work arround it ,
thanks in advance

i used  exclamation mark (!) to turn off typescript safty check but didn't work

Comment: You're passing an array to a function expecting a string, so obviously it can't work. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: I know that you are right , Iam confused, it should work but obviously it didn't work

Comment: Why on Earth should it work? You're passing the wrong kind of data to the function.

Comment: okay  tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

I should use for roles property in adminService the data type with list square brackets

```
roles : string[]
```

I have no idea why the vscode does not accept it in the first place,
Thanks for help.

Comment: Hello, if you don't mean to provide an answer to your own question, you should use the `edit` button to  add further information. I advise you to delete this answer and integrate it in your question